# AJAX POST Send Multiple DIV value

Tags: ajax, post, multiple-value

I would like to send my dynamically generated DIV items, but I do not understand how to do it

I create my div dynamically:

```
$("#clt_forf_ti").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_input){
                x++;
                var addDIV = $('<div id="clt_forf_div'+x+'" class="w-100 form-control" ><label for="clt_forf_num'+x+'">Ligne :</label> <input type="text" class="font-weight-bold border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 mR-10" id="clt_forf_num'+x+'" autocomplete="off" style="width: 100px" > Forfait : <i id="clt_forf_forf_select'+x+'" style="display:none;"></i><input type="text" class="border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0" id="clt_forf_forf'+x+'" autocomplete="off" style="width: 180px"><i class="ti-calendar mL-20 mR-5"></i><input type="text" class="border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0" id="clt_forf_date_start'+x+'" name="datepicker" placeholder="Début" style="width: 80px"><i class="ti-calendar mL-20 mR-5"></i><input type="text" class="border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0" id="clt_forf_date_end'+x+'" name="datepicker" placeholder="Fin" style="width: 80px"><i id="clt_forf_ti_remove" class="ti-close c-red-500 mL-5" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></div>');

                $('#clt_forf_bloc').append(addDIV);
                $('#clt_forf_forf'+x, addDIV).autocomplete(autocomp_opt);
                $("input[id^='clt_forf_date']", addDIV).datepicker(datepick);
                //$('#clt_forf_date_end'+x, addDIV).datepicker(datepick);
            }
        });
```

I want to send each value by ajax:

```
var data = {
                op_clt_forf_ref: $("[id^='clt_forf_forf_select']").html(),
                op_clt_forf_num: $("[id^='clt_forf_num']").val(),
                op_clt_forf_start: $("[id^='clt_forf_date_start']").val(),
                op_clt_forf_end: $("[id^='clt_forf_date_end']").val(),
                op_clt_forf_nom: $("[id^='clt_forf_forf']").val(),
            };
```

however he only takes me the first div and not the others,

can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Elements that you have created were not present in the DOM earlier. So can't target them directly.
Try doing this:

```
var data = {
            op_clt_forf_ref: $('body #clt_forf_forf_select').html(),
            op_clt_forf_num: $('body #clt_forf_num').val(),
            op_clt_forf_start: $('body #clt_forf_date_start').val(),
            op_clt_forf_end: $('body #clt_forf_date_end').val(),
            op_clt_forf_nom: $('body #clt_forf_forf').val(),
        };
```

Comment: my PHP code that receives the data from AJAX, how will it receive data from for example: op_clt_forf_ref
Knowing that there will be several op_clt_forf_ref, op_clt_forf_ref2, op_clt_forf_ref3 etc ...
You see ? :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it

Comment: for exemple when i click on 'add' i have a new div : `<div id="op_clt_forf_ref"></div>` when i click again i have : `<div id="op_clt_forf_ref2"></div>` in my `var data = {op_clt_forf_ref= $("???")}` I do not know what to put in it to automatically take both DIV created

Comment: ohh! okay. Now I get it

Comment: :) :) you can help me ?

Comment: hmmm. I'm trying

Comment: I think you should add a common class to all the dynamically generated div's and then simply target it using class

Comment: yes, i have do this : `<input type="text" class="font-weight-bold border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 mR-10 **numeros'+x+'**">` but no effect

Comment: i test this : `var count = 0;
                var numeros = $('.numeros').each(function(){
                        count = count + 1;
                        $(this).serialize();
                    });` and `data-ajax = {to-php: numeros,}`   but not work too :/

Comment: I'VE SOLVE MY QUESTION WITH THIS / https://www.webslesson.info/2017/03/multiple-inline-insert-data-using-ajax-jquery-php.html